# Oak of Tabor VS Mount Tabor?

Tags: 1-samuel, judges

In 1 Samuel 10:3 (NASB)

> Then you will go on further from there, and you will come as far as the **oak of Tabor**, and there three men going up to God at Bethel will meet you: one carrying three young goats, another carrying three loaves of bread, and another carrying a jug of wine.

In Judges 4:6 (NASB)

> Now she sent word and summoned Barak the son of Abinoam from Kedesh-naphtali, and said to him, “The Lord, the God of Israel, has indeed commanded, ‘Go and march to **Mount Tabor**, and take with you ten thousand men from the sons of Naphtali and from the sons of Zebulun.

Is the oak of Tabor located in the Mount Tabor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things given the name "Tabor":

1. A mountain on the **border of Issachar**, Josh 19:22 (which may have been close to #2 below).  It appears to be associated with an island mountain in Jer 46:18,  and mount Herman in Ps 89:12, and served as the rallying point for Naphtali and Zebulun in Judges 4:6, 12, 14, etc.
2. A town in the Territory of Zebulun, 1 Chr 6:77, Josh 19:22
3. An Oak tree in **Benjamin**, 1 Sam 10:3.

Thus, if the location be any guide, then Benjamin too far from the border of Issachar and Zebulun.  Thus, the Oak Tabor and the mount Tabor were separated by a significant distance.